# How to remove a disk that is not safely removed?

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount

I am new to ubuntu. Unfortunately, I removed my usb stick without using safely remove or other stuff. Now Ubuntu doesn't recognize my usb stick and Gnome Disk Utility is looked like this:

[image: gnome-disk-utility]

I looked around for solution but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I assume that it is just a matter of the file system being corrupted by the unsafe removal - this would usually be the issue, but I cannot tell 100% for you case:

USB flash drives usually are `vfat` file systems. You can try to repair it with `fsck`, namely `fsck.vfat` as the version for `vfat` file systems.

Open a terminal an follow these steps (detailed as you said to be new to Ubuntu):

First of all you need to identify its name in the `/dev/` directory. For this unplug the drive, then just type in `cd /dev` (enter after each command is implied), then `ls` to list the directories entries. Note which `sdxy` (x=letter, y=digit) entries are listed. Plug in the device, type `ls` again and look for a new `sdxy`. If there is none you have severe problems, if there is, we can start repairing it.

Second. Say we found our device as `/dev/sdb1`, then run `fsck.vfat -n /dev/sdb1` first. This is a dry run listing the errors only. Once you had read of these you can either repair it fully automatically `fsck.vfat -a /dev/sdb1` or interactively with `fsck.vfat -r /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Welcome. Remember to unmount it properly in future.

Answer (score 0):

If your system doesn't recognize your USB, it is damaged already.

You last chance is to see if you can see your device in the output of this command:

```
lsusb
```

You must always 'safe remove' your pen-drive. If you cannot do it, go through these lines:

Lets assume your device is `/dev/sdb1`. Run this command:

```
sudo umount -f /dev/sdb1
```

If you don't know what is the file system, run

```
sudo blkid
```

and find your partition in the list

Comment: Well, I've already tried 'lsusb', my usb is not listed there. So can we assume it is damaged? If so, how can remove it from device list anyway?

Comment: It is damaged. You can safely through it out :P

Comment: Just before that, make sure it won't work on any other system

Comment: I will definetely try that out